# spring security 4.0.1 Invalid CSRF token found on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security

i am trying to use the following project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/gae-xml to use spring security within a GAE context. 
In this project their is no freemarker at all, and its goal is to allow a user that is logged in gmail to access the application.
In spring security 4.0.1 CSRF is by default enabled. I tried to deploy the app to a personal GAE application and got the following trace org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter doFilterInternal: Invalid CSRF token found for http://xxx/_ah/queue/__deferre in my log console. Adding

```
<csrf disabled="true"/>
```

in the applicationContext-security.xml remove this error but it is a nonsense to add this line.
If anyone tried this tutorial i would appreciate a lot any advice.